# CSS set element max-width to body width minus x

Tags: html, css

I have an `img` attribute in my HTML. I would like for the `max-width` of this element to be equal to the width of the body minus a number, say 60.

How would I do this? I've tried this:

```
img
{
    max-width:body.width - 60;
}
```

But it seems that the element width is set to 60 instead.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can perform calculations right in the CSS itself, using the calc function, which would look like this in your example:

```
img
{
    max-width: calc(100% - 60px);
}
```

It's important to note though that this it's still an "experimental" feature, but current support is surprisingly good. You can find out more about browsers support here: 
http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can! But you won't able to get the body's width you'll only able to use *literal values* (if you know the `width` of the `body`, use that value. If you want a "liquid" solution, use percentage values on the `body` element.

In a close future, we can do this using the `attr()` function. For example:

```
img { width: calc(attr(body.width) - 200px); } /* This is an idea */
```

Check this **[link](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/CR-css3-values-20130730/#attr-notation)**.

---

You can do that with the `calc()` function

Check this **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/F9UVw/1/)**

**Be careful! Respect the spaces inside the function!**

This won't work:

```
img { height: calc(100px-50px) }
```

The above example would work if you respect the spaces:

```
img { height: calc(100px - 50px) }
```

Comment: Could you give an example?

Comment: @Undo You can find some great examples here: http://css-tricks.com/a-couple-of-use-cases-for-calc/

Comment: img { max-width: calc(100% - 60px); } note, it's not supported in all browsers / versions though.

Comment: Sure, but for me to provide it as an answer (with good conscience), I want to provide more info about where it's supported. Will do that in a few min.

Comment: @RobM OK - I only really care about it in WebKit, as this CSS will only be used in an app.

Answer (score 3):

You will be able to do it with the `calc()` function.

```
#someDiv {
    width: calc(100% - 60px);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS padding:

```
img {
    width:100%;
    padding: 0 30px;
}
```